# Order of priority in hybridization of d-orbitals

Tags: physical-chemistry, orbitals, hybridization, valence-bond-theory

During hybridization of d-orbitals why the $d_{z^2}$ and $d_{x^2-y^2}$ orbitals are used up before the $d_{xy}$, $d_{yz}$ and $d_{zx}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotational frame of reference which defined which axis is the z-axis is changed such that $d_{z^2}$ and $d_{x^2-y^2}$ are hybridized first is a convention / practice.

In theory (meaning mathematically), you should be able to get equivalent geometry if you used the other d orbitals for hybridzation.

Basically the donut thing is weird enough we try to fold it in so we can deal with the more normal cloverleafs as leftovers.

Comment: Of course hybridisation with d orbitals doesn't really happen, not even in a theoretical way.